# Como deixar um gráfico pizza clicável

Tags: angularjs

Minha dúvida é como faço para deixar um gráfico pizza (pie chart) clicável. Tipo, invocar uma função para filtrar uma lista a partir do click numa das parte do gráfico. Atualmente estou usando o **[Angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/)**, mas não consegui, mesmo com o material, subsídios para manipular da forma que preciso. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisar adicionar o evento `pie -> dispatch -> elementClick` nas opções do gráfico:

```
pie: {
  dispatch: {
    elementClick: function(evento){ console.log(evento) }
  }
}
```

```js
angular
  .module('meuApp', ['nvd3'])
  .controller('MeuController', MeuController);

MeuController.$inject = [];

function MeuController() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.opcoes = {
    chart: {
      type: 'pieChart',
      pie: {
        dispatch: {
          elementClick: function(evento){ console.log(evento) }
        }
      },
      height: 500,
      x: function(d) {
        return d.key;
      },
      y: function(d) {
        return d.y;
      },
      showLabels: true,
      duration: 500,
      labelThreshold: 0.01,
      labelSunbeamLayout: true,
      legend: {
        margin: {
          top: 5,
          right: 35,
          bottom: 5,
          left: 0
        }
      }
    }
  };

  vm.dados = [
    {key: "One", y: 5},
    {key: "Two", y: 2},
    {key: "Three", y: 9},
    {key: "Four", y: 7},
    {key: "Five", y: 4},
    {key: "Six", y: 3},
    {key: "Seven", y: .5}
  ];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-nvd3/1.0.5/angular-nvd3.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="meuApp">
  <div ng-controller="MeuController as vm">
    <nvd3 options="vm.opcoes" data="vm.dados"></nvd3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show mesmo! +1.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pior que a documentação é meio obscura

Comment: não me parece tanto http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart, achei que é até fácil para quem não tem costume de ler aquelas docs mais completas, como gerados do javaDOC e phpDOC. Achei bem quickstart :)

Comment: @Sorack, agradeço mais uma vez, brother. Abraço.

Comment: @Sorack, voltando as dúvidas. Como faço para, tipo, colocar uma parte clicável no meio do piechart donut? No meu gráfico, tem um pedaço "all", que retorna todos os dados. Só que eu não queria colocar mais um pedaço no gráfico, e sim no meio dele. Como faço?